# Count how many sections in a article (there is more then one article)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´d like to know how many sections are in the article with class "class1" or "class2".

```
<article class="class1">
    <section>
        <p>example</p>
    </section>
</article>
<article class="class2>
    <section>
        <p>text</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>example</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: `$('article.class1, article.class2').children('section').length`

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
$("article section").length
```

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7284qyj/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   var count = 0;
   var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1")
   for (var i = 0; i < class1.length; i++){
      for (var e = 0; e < class1[i].childNodes.length; e++){
          if (class1[i].childNodes[e].nodeName == "SECTION") {
             count++;
          }
      }
    }
   var class2 = document.getElementsByClassName("class2")
   for (var i = 0; i < class2.length; i++){
      for (var e = 0; e < class2[i].childNodes.length; e++){
          if (class2[i].childNodes[e].nodeName == "SECTION") {
             count++;
          }
      }
    }

    alert(count);
```

Thats how you can do it in JavaScript without JQuery, but i have to admit, JQuery is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$("article section").length
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bp36x20d/2/)

Comment: @Amit - he wants counts for **section** not article :) ;)

Comment: @KashyapVyas it will return count not artical check fiddle.

Comment: @Amit - please read question carefully :) ,,,,, right answer may be `alert($("article section").length)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function sessionInArticle(articleClass){
    return $("." + articleClass + " section").length;
}

var article1 = sessionInArticle("class1");//how many sesion in article 1
```

To get all you could do:

```
var sections = 0;
$("article").each(function(){
    sections += sessionInArticle($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the answer i wanted to know! I added it immediately to my project.